# TeamViewer upgrade

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, teamviewer

I'm having second thoughts about uninstalling previous version of TeamViewer. Now I have version 11 installed. I upgraded from version 10 by directly exexuting the version 11 installer. As you can see, in the Linux Mint 17.3 menu, there are 2 icons, both of which launch the same version of the program (11). I want to remove version 10. The problem is, as I said both of these icons run the same version of the program, I don't want to uninstall the latest version.

[image: TeamViewer 10 and 11]

How do I know, if those icons now launch the same version of the program, when I click on Uninstall on TeamViewer 10, it will NOT uninstall the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I clicked on Uninstall on TeamViewer 10. And the following appeared:

[image]

As stated, this menu item is not associated with any package. So, after confirming, that I want to remove it from the menu anyway, the menu item is gone.